# Computing real depth map of image objects and reconstruction from several images

Tags: ios, opencv, computer-vision, distance, triangulation

I have a next task: get a room 3d projection from multiple images (possible video stream, doesn't matter). There will be spherical camera (in fact multiple cameras on sphere-like construction), so the case is the right one on the image. [image]

I decided to code it on iOS platform as I'm iOS developer and model cameras with iPhone cam rotating it as shown on the pic above. As I can decompose this task, first I need to get real distance to the objects (walls in most cases, I think). Is it possible? Which algoritms/methods should I use to achieve this? I don't ask you to make the task for me obviously, but give me the direction, because I have no idea, maybe some equations/tutorials/algorithms with explanation to my case. Thank you!

Comment: How did you go on about it? Any hints what technologies you are using?

Answer (score 2):

The task of building a 3D model from multiple 2D images is called "scene reconstruction." It's still an active area of research, but solutions involve recognizing the same keypoint (e.g. a distinctive part of an object) in two images. Once you have that, you can use the known camera geometry to solve for the 3D position of that keypoint in the world.

Here's a reference:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d18/tutorial_sfm_scene_reconstruction.html#gsc.tab=0

You can google "scene reconstruction" to find lots more, and papers that go into more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, at first glance didn't recognize anything similar to distance to objects in the tutorial. "you can use the known camera geometry to solve for the 3D position of that keypoint in the world" can you tell me more about it?

Comment: My link above was a library that seems to do the scene reconstruction for you. It's fairly complicated. If you want to understand how it works, you could read the slides and references about "camera models", "epipolar geometry", and "stereo systems" here: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs231a/schedule.html